# What is the maximum size of JSON string passed by Npgsql?

Tags: json, postgresql, npgsql

I am calling a Postgresql stored procedure from `.Net` application using `Npgsql`.

One of the parameters is of type: `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Json`

What is the maximum allowed size/length of JSON string that can be passed as a value of that parameter?

Answer (score 1):

At the protocol wire level, parameters are sent as part of the PostgreSQL Bind message. As [the docs specify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html), each parameter has a 32-bit signed length prefix. The maximum size you can represent with that is 2GB. Note that I've never verified this in any way - this is a maximum theoretical limit, but practical limits may be lower for various reasons.

Another note: [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html) indicates that the maximum size for a field is 1GB. That may also apply to parameters although this isn't explicitly said.

Comment: To verify that practically, do you suggest "trying it", by passing a 1GB-text as a parameter?

Comment: Sure, why not. One thing would be to simply use a parameter to insert a 1GB value into a column, and another would be to send an even bigger parameter which would get truncated server-side before getting inserted (or whatever). The latter would test the ability of parameter values to go up to 2GB even though fields cannot.

Comment: I ran out of memory before i could reach that size of string to test :)